# location extracted from wit.ai is blank in facebook messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I'm using Wit.ai to extract the location from a sentence. When I execute the bot in Wit.ai to reflect the location it works perfectly

```
how is the weather in California?

You asked about the weather in California
```

But when I connect the Wit.ai API to my node JS app (simple, straight forward app using "RunActions") to connect to facebook messenger I get

```
how is the weather in California?

You asked about the weather in
```

There is a blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work in Console because we emulate a function to manage the context. But you will have to implement a function on your side to carry/update the context. We removed the mandatory "merge" but you can use or even create your own merge function that will look at the entities and eventually update the context when some entities exist

Look at the fetchWeather example here: https://wit-ai.github.io/witty-fiddle/?id=5a387f6ccb4be4a1f77f2113747a558a